# Odd Apple AirPort Express behaviour

Tags: airport-express

I've been using a rather old AirPort Express for home Wi-Fi for a number of years. (It's old enough that it only supports WPA, not WPA2 -- perhaps this is an indication that I should upgrade!)

In the last week I've been experiencing very slow internet over the Wi-Fi. Suspecting that someone outside my home was leeching from me (despite a reasonable password and MAC address filtering turned on) I decided to change some settings: I changed the SSID, turned off broadcast of the SSID and changed the password.

After these changes, I managed to connect using the new password on my iPad. But on the other devices I tried (iPhone, PS3) I was not able to connect. **In fact, I only succeeded in connecting when I entered my OLD password!**

Is this a known issue with ancient AirPort Express units? Is my unit cracked and unrecoverable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you must have purchased that 802.11g AirPort Express during the first few months of its availability in the summer of 2004, and never upgraded the firmware. I believe a firmware update supporting WPA2 for that model was released before the end of 2004. What firmware version are you running, 6.0? I believe 6.3 is the latest for that model.

<s>Could it be that you changed the base station's administrator password, but not its wireless network password? Or that your change didn't "stick" for some reason?</s> (Edit: Never mind, I re-read your question and realized you'd connected from your iPad with the new password.)

Try power-cycling your Express to make sure the change had a chance to take effect. Then go back into the AirPort Utility and tell it to show you your network password, and see what it says.

You might also want to take this opportunity to update to firmware 6.3. Or buy the new 2012 AirPort Express, which seems to be getting [good](http://gizmodo.com/5921456/apple-airport-express-2012-lightning-review-probably-the-best-router-ever) [reviews](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167395/new_airport_express_a_tiny_wi_fi_base_station_powerhouse.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was doing this all late last night, so there's definitely a chance of user error in the equation. I'll double-check everything, upgrade the firmware and see how it goes.

Comment: Result: I hadn't changed the wireless network password. (I don't know why the iPad still connected. Password caching?) The option was hidden and not called "password" so I missed it. My firmware is 6.2, but I can't upgrade because the upgrade utility won't run on Vista or Win7! I'm considering buying the new AirPort Express. Thanks for your help!